# How to get individual kernel timing with clEnqueueTask by sending Kernel_event?

Tags: kernel, opencl, time.h

I am trying for task parallelism on a GPU Simulator., instead of EnQueueNDRangeKernel, i'm using EnQueueTask(with 4 diff kernels) with out-of-order-execution-mode-enable.. 
I have two host pointers, when i am trying to write those two on global memory, they are doing wrongly because of asynchronous mode.. i created one user event like..

```
clSetUserEventStatus(user_event, CL_COMPLETE);
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, Amobj, CL_TRUE, 0, 16*16*sizeof(float), A, 1, &user_event, NULL);
clSetUserEventStatus(user_event, CL_COMPLETE);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, Bmobj, CL_TRUE, 0, 16*16*sizeof(float), B, 1, &user_event, NULL);
```

but it is not giving correct results, are its stalling sometimes..

```
cl_event timing_event1, timing_event2, timing_event3, timing_event4;
cl_ulong starttime1=0,starttime2=0,starttime3=0,starttime4=0,
         endtime1=0,endtime2=0,endtime3=0,endtime4=0,
         time_spent1,time_spent2=0,time_spent3=0,time_spent4=0, time_spent_all_0=0, time_spent_all_1=0;
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel[0], 0, NULL, &timing_event1);
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel[1], 0, NULL, &timing_event2);
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel[2], 0, NULL, &timing_event3);
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel[3], 0, NULL, &timing_event4);

  clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event1,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(cl_ulong),&starttime1,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event1,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(cl_ulong),&endtime1,NULL);
time_spent1 = endtime1 - starttime1;
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event2,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(cl_ulong),&starttime2,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event2,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(cl_ulong),&endtime2,NULL);
time_spent2 = endtime2 - starttime2;
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event3,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(cl_ulong),&starttime3,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event3,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(cl_ulong),&endtime3,NULL);
time_spent3 = endtime3 - starttime3;
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event4,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(cl_ulong),&starttime4,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event4,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(cl_ulong),&endtime4,NULL);
time_spent4 = endtime4 - starttime4;

time_spent_all_0 = time_spent1 + time_spent2 + time_spent3 + time_spent4;
time_spent_all_1 = endtime4 - starttime1;

printf("\n time_spent1 = %llu", time_spent1);
printf("\n time_spent2 = %llu", time_spent2);
printf("\n time_spent3 = %llu", time_spent3);
printf("\n time_spent4 = %llu", time_spent4);
printf("\n time_spent_all_0 = %llu", time_spent_all_0);
printf("\n time_spent_all_1 = %llu\n", time_spent_all_1);
```

After doing this i am getting all zero's..

```
 size_t resolution;
  clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_PROFILING_TIMER_RESOLUTION, sizeof(resolution), &resolution, NULL);
  printf("resolution size : %d", resolution);
```

After doing this i am getting a large number like 17145896522 .. what is meant by this?

Now my doubt is., where i need to put `clFlush` and `clFinish` in my code?? I want each individual kernel timing and total all kernels timing..?
if this is not worth then suggest me any other method to get exact timing info in milliseconds or microseconds or nanoseconds..

Thanks in advance..

---

I added my results after correcting code..

```
gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel[0], 0, NULL, &kernel_event1);
printf("Enqueue Task 0 successful: %d\n",ret);
gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel[1], 0, NULL, &kernel_event2);
printf("Enqueue Task 1 successful: %d\n",ret);
gettimeofday( &t3, NULL );
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel[2], 0, NULL, &kernel_event3);
printf("Enqueue Task 2 successful: %d\n",ret);
gettimeofday( &t4, NULL );
ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel[3], 0, NULL, &kernel_event4);
printf("Enqueue Task 3 successful: %d\n",ret);
gettimeofday( &t5, NULL );
clFinish(command_queue);

ret = clGetEventProfilingInfo(kernel_event1, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(cl_ulong), &starttime1, NULL);
printf("profiling starttime 1 : %d\n",ret);
ret = clGetEventProfilingInfo(kernel_event1, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &endtime1,NULL);
time_spent1 = endtime1 - starttime1;
printf("time_spent 1 = %llu\t profiling endtime 1 = %d\n", time_spent1, ret);

profiling starttime 1 : 0
time_spent 1 = 0
profiling endtime 1 = 0
```

These are the results i am getting., so what i can do now?

Comment: i saw one question with EnqueueNDRangeKernel with command_queue profiling info, i tried that also, but i got nothing.. that's why i posted this new question, keep it mind i'm working on simulator (GPU Hardware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add **CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE** when creating the command queue.

Check the return codes for each OpenCL call, especially the **clCreateCommandQueue** call, since profiling may not be available on your device.

You need to wait for your enqueued commands to terminate before getting the profiling info. For example by inserting a **clFinish** after the 4 enqueues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice., Yes., i added that command_queue property CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE., i dint check that return status, so i will do that., ok i will add clFinish after all Enqueue commands, then is there any cl command to wait?? and one more thing, why my output is wrong when i am performing out-of-order execution? i observed that my two buffers also writing parallel y, i think that's the problem, so how to overcome it?

Comment: Hello Eric.. Finally i got it.. Thank you so much for your advice.. command_queue profiling info is not available from the device what i am using.. my prob is solved.!